# I've got a Radeon R5 graphics card - what drivers do I need?

Tags: drivers

What drivers do I need to make my graphics card work? My details are below.

VGA compatible controller  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R5 Graphics]

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you. Is your graphics card not working? Please include in your question A) What you saw, B) What you expected to see and C) What you've tried. Thank you!

Comment: just bought new pc but ive only got drivers for windows but ive got ubuntu graphics card is brand new but the place where i bought the pc say i need to download drivers for the card and ive tried a few games and it was quite laggy and ive tried to find my card on your site but could not find it.

Comment: I usually go to the chipset manufacturer for drivers: did you try http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to install proprietary drivers. Take a look at the following site :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: when i was checking if my card was supported on the amd website it only comes up with windows 7/8? not linux

Comment: The release note associated with the following says your graphics is supported. http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86
it's another way if the method above does not succeed:download driver and build it for your system.

Comment: once ive dowloaded this what will i need to do

Comment: Maybe read carefuly once more the 1st link about binary drivers. Section 3 explain what to do for drivers downloaded manualy from AMD website.

Comment: this is confusing the hell out of me

Comment: Did you try it ? What is the issue ? all is explained, and you just have to execute the commands...